# Android - Turn textView into a log output

Tags: java, android

I have textView that I would like to turn into a simple log of what stage of a loop the program is currently in.

For example if I press a button:

```
public void doThis(View view) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
my_text.setText(j+"");          
        }
    }
```

This overwrites the text in the textView though. How would I go about creating something where the textView would say:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 6):

You can append text `my_text.append(j+"\n");`

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should use LogCat and [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class for logging.
But if you want to use a TextView you should do this way:

```
public void doThis(View view) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
       my_text.append(j+"\n");          
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And yes, I know to use the log class, but I was curious. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this helps, If you need to log a string. Use this..

```
Log.i("LogCat Tag", textview);
```